# Add/Delete/Update any chosen table’s data in SQL server 2008 database

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008

In WPF  I need  to Add/Delete/Update any chosen table’s data in SQL server 2008 database, I am thinking of using DataGrid  control  and bind the chosen table to do it, So any recommended Control to Choose from frame work 4.0? I appreciate your help.

Comment: How are you going to decide which tables data to be bounded with grid? What I mean is, in Grid first you list the data, then edit any data, then how you are going to bind multiple table to a grid?

Comment: I show the list of available table Names in the ComboBox , On select bind the table to the WPF DataGrid, After edit/add/delete update the datagrid data back to SQL Table. I have’t tried the multiple table into the same grid but it seems possible you may search within   StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success but not very clean (WPF Data Grid requires SQLCommandBuilder help to Insert/update/Delete & the table require primary key but works). Also Explored third-party and found DevEx & Telerik WPF Data Grid comes with the dynamic binding add/update/delete features, yet I have to code and see is it worth introducing third party dependency to get slightly better user experience.